# Similar spring components with different property names

Tags: java, spring

ActiveMQConnectionFactory use **brokerURL** property for storing server address.
TibjmsConnectionFactory use **serverUrl** property for storing server address.

Is it possible to define bean in Spring configuration in a way that they can be switched from properties file?
For example:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="${listener.connection.factory}">
    <property name="XXX" value="${in.serverUrl}" />
</bean>
```

Where XXX act as brokerURL or serverUrl - depending on connection factory.

I know that profiles can be used to achieve this, but it looks like a very simple problem, that can be solved easily.

Answer (score 0):

Property names unfortunately cannot be based on PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, so you cannot have it based off a property value. These are a few ways that I can think of:

1. Use java `@Configuration` if feasible(Spring 3.2+), you can then create one or the other connectionfactory based on custom property values
2. Like you noted but discounted, profiles is a very good fit for this kind of a scenario.
3. A little bit of an overkill approach, create a [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html), which creates one or the other connection factory based on some flag that you pass to your custom factory bean.